# Eclipse is not working

Tags: eclipse

The first time I used eclipse it worked fine. For other reasons I deleted and downloaded again the JDK, SDK. However when trying to start eclipse I got this

"Java was not Started but returned exit code=1".

In searching for an answer I found a few solutions involving changing eclipse ini file which I did to this.

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.1.1.R36x_v20101122_1400.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.2.R36x_v20101222
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256M
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vm
C:\Java\JDK\1.5\bin\javaw.exe-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
-Xms40m
-Xmx384_
```

Now when I start Eclipse I get this.

```
 ...Java JRE or JDK must be available in order to run Eclipse No Java Virtual Macj=hine was found in the following locations
 C\java\JDK\1.5\java.exe-vmargs
```

At this point I can not seem to find what I am doing wrong. If I edited the ini file then the full edit would help. Some of the edits did not show the entire file so I am not sure if I did it right. I am trying to edit ini file just to see if I can get something to work but any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

For some reason Eclipse looks in C:\java\JDK\1.5\bin for javaw.exe.  Did you tinker with the eclipse.ini file?

I would suggest reinstalling Java to the same location as before, or reunzip Eclipse to get rid of any changed configuration files.

You can install a public Java Runtime easily by going to java.com.

Answer (score 0):

Every option switch and value must be on a separate line in the eclipse.ini file, and on Windows you must have the lines separated by CR+LF.

Answer (score 0):

**For windows 7 - 64 bit users ( may work for others too )**
 you may do the following

**1.** If the java Runtime is NOT already installed, (Note it doesnt get installed on its own you need to download). You can download from here http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html (select 'Java Platform (JDK) 7u21' out of the three option the first button :) )

after install you will find javaw.exe in " C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6\bin"

**2** set the environment variable the steps as below

a) Right click Computer, select properties, select 'advance system setting'

b) Under Advanced tab select the last button 'Environment Variable'

c) Under System settings in the window that comes next search for 'Path'

d) select 'Path' click edit

e) Add the  '**; C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6\bin**'  (semi colon is used to separate  if some other variable already exists, and no need of quote ;) )

Thats all !! Now try running Eclipse.exe ( **note : if you have added the entry in eclipse.ini as suggested by some ..please remove it else it will throw another exception**)

**Remember no need to change the eclipse.ini**

It works  Just double click the eclipse.exe :)

Answer (score 0):

I re-downloaded eclipse and the latest version of java. I think it says that you don't have the correct java version installed. It worked  fine after I re-downloaded them.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem just now. I reinstalled the JDK and it sarted working again.